# Issue starting firebase emulator node 17

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-tools

After running "firebase emulators:start" the following error occurs:

```
> emulate
> firebase emulators:start

i  emulators: Starting emulators: auth, functions, firestore, hosting, storage
⚠  functions: The following emulators are not running, calls to these services from the Functions emulator will affect production: database, pubsub
⚠  Your requested "node" version "16" doesn't match your global version "17". Using node@17 from host.
i  firestore: Firestore Emulator logging to firestore-debug.log
i  emulators: Shutting down emulators.
i  functions: Stopping Functions Emulator
i  firestore: Stopping Firestore Emulator
i  hub: Stopping emulator hub

Error: TIMEOUT: Port 8080 on localhost was not active within 60000ms
```

I recently upgraded my system node version from 16 to 17, does this cause the issue?

node v17.5.0

firebase-tools v10.2.1

firestore-debug.log

```
Feb 19, 2022 5:31:26 PM com.google.cloud.datastore.emulator.firestore.websocket.WebSocketServer start
INFO: Started WebSocket server on ws://localhost:52565
API endpoint: http://localhost:8080
If you are using a library that supports the FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST environment variable, run:

   export FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:8080

Dev App Server is now running.

*** shutting down gRPC server since JVM is shutting down
*** server shut down
```

Comment: is there any output in `firestore-debug.log` ?

Comment: Feb 19, 2022 4:34:48 PM com.google.cloud.datastore.emulator.firestore.websocket.WebSocketServer start
INFO: Started WebSocket server on ws://localhost:54429
API endpoint: http://localhost:8080
If you are using a library that supports the FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST environment variable, run:

   export FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:8080

Dev App Server is now running.

*** shutting down gRPC server since JVM is shutting down
*** server shut down

Comment: node v17.5.0
firebase-tools v10.2.1

Comment: quick fix was downgrading to node v16.14.0